# FuelPHP - is it production ready?

Tags: php, frameworks, fuelphp

I'm just doing a comparison of different frameworks - pros and cons, benchmarking, that sort of thing. I need the comparison for a future project.

In doing so I came across FuelPHP, which has Phil Sturgeon working on it. I recognise the name from some of his CodeIgniter plugins.

Has anyone used it for a project yet? Would you say it's anything like production-ready?

Comment: sorry about my answer earlier. thanks for flagging it, I agree it wasn't accurate.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

We're working towards the 1.0 final release and we're close. As we've been in a feature freeze as of RC1 the API won't change anymore, this is what we wrote about API stability then:

> Now that we are in a feature freeze
>   and heading to v1.0, legacy code and
>   applications will start to become much
>   more of a concern. We won't be the
>   sort of framework where everything
>   breaks every time the number changes.
>   For example, v1.0.x will be backwards
>   compatible but v1.1 may have some
>   minor changes - which most likely will
>   just be a find and replace across the
>   app folder. v2.0? Well that will be a
>   different story.

Most of the bugs we're aware of have been fixed and there's still a small list of bugs left to fix which our small but active community have been very helpfull with. One of the major hurdles left is writing Unit tests for all parts of the Core and the packages.

I am myself already developing production software on it, though that's slated for a summer release and Dan Horrigan (our project lead) has had his employer switch to Fuel for their production.

Comment: Thanks @Jelmer. I'm going to have a play tomorrow instead of watching the Royal Wedding.

Answer (score 3):

I've personally used it and think it is great but it's just advisable to know that it's on Release Candidate status at the moment.

> We strongly urge you to download Fuel and give it a try. Obviously no promises can be made about being 100% stable but what software ever can? Fuel is stable enough that you can start using it to develop your applications, but it should go without saying that any application needs testing before going live anyway.

From the blog post http://fuelphp.com/blog/2011/04/start-your-engines-fuel-rc1-is-here

All in all I'd say if you've got the time to try it then go for it - IMHO it's one of best up-and-coming frameworks out there and ALOT of thought has gone into the design of it. You can pick up RC2 here https://github.com/downloads/fuel/fuel/fuel-1.0-rc2.zip

P.S. I am in no way affiliated with Fuel - I just like it :-D

Comment: Yeah I like the look of it too. It's kind of like CodeIgniter v7.0.

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not "Production Ready".

They havn't finished the unittests.
(ones, that you should write before you code each class)

Which, kinda, means that API might change ( even though they call it RC2 ).

Comment: Why would the API change? If there is a bug then we'd just fix it, no recode the API. ;-)

Comment: @Phil-Sturgeon sure , if the bug is in algorithm and not structural/design flaw.